# Weston screen blanking

Tags: linux, screensaver, wayland

How is it done to turn off screen blanking in Weston with wayland backend not X. I have tried:

```
setterm -blank 0
setterm -powersave off
setterm -powerdown 0
echo -ne "\033[9;0]" >> /etc/issue
echo 0 > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/blank
```

As well in weston.ini i set the screensaver duration to 0. But that section is confusing because it says to uncomment path to disable screensaver. But after 10 minutes the screen still turns off.

This distro was built with yocto core-image-weston.

Answer (score 3):

From [man pages for weston.ini](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/weston.ini.5.html), to disable screen locking, add next lines:

```
[core]
idle-time=0

[shell]
locking=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `idle-time=0` under `[core]`, in `weston.ini`.

[Source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/weston.ini.5.html)